# Should our tabletop play styles question be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, list-questions

I'm referring to this question from 2012: [Tabletop Play Style Classification Schemes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/16380/1204)

It was mod-created to replace a previous question, and has attracted 1-3 high quality answers (going by votes). But it's also a list question, with the caveat that not many people have gone to the effort of answering well.

I suspect it should be closed as too broad (and not placed on historical lock, so that it can remain editable), and I'd usually just go ahead and vote that way and leave a comment, but I get the feeling I may be missing something this time.

Is this question worthwhile leaving open, or should it be closed as no longer meeting our quality standards?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I got that feeling too when I recently linked to it, but the cognitive dissonance between how useful I've found it and its list-like-ness left me unsure what to really think.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I feel similarly, it is an excellent topic to cover

Comment: As a matter of record: The question has been placed on historical lock at 03:38Z. (This question was asked at 1:58Z.)

Comment: Why is it important that it still be editable?

Comment: @C.Ross so that it can be edited, and because it doesn't seem so bad a situation that editing needs to stop too. Either way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has been historical locked.